# How to stop the inclusion of file imported in a file , the file in which the latter has been included in C

Tags: c, include

Like a.c has the code

```
#include "b.h"
```

b.h has:

```
#include "c.h"
```

c.h has:

```
void fun()
{

}
```

here i want to restrict a.c from acessing fun but I want b.h to access c.h

Comment: Look up "include guard".  But also, avoid putting function definitions in header files.  Headers should contain only *declarations*, not definitions.  For example, `void fun(void);`.

Comment: Moreover, although you can avoid `b.h` providing a declaration or definition of `fun()`, that would not prevent code in `a.c` from calling that function if it is defined somewhere in the program.

Answer (score 1):

If file `A.c` includes file `B.h`, and file `B.h` includes file `C.h`, and file `C.h` contains function `func` - then `A` can call `func` - this is just how the language works.

---

What you can do *instead* is to move `C.h`'s import into a `B.c` - which **isn't** included in `A.c` - and thus prevent the inclusion of `func` in `A.c`. But then you have to separate `B` into `.h` and `.c` - and compile `B.c` explicitly.

---

As John pointed out in the comments, you should add include guards to every `.h` file, e.g.:

```
#ifndef _B_H_
#define _B_H_

...

#endif
```

This prevents function declarations from getting reincluded. Also - it is bad practice to implement functions (e.g. `int func() { }`) in your `.h` files - instead you should include only their definition (e.g. `int func();`) and move their implementation to a separate `.c` file.

Comment: Yes, you can do that in the OP's very simple example, but that approach runs against best practices in many real-world cases, and is altogether unworkable in some of them.  Exactly what the OP asks for is provided by conventional include guards.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Include guards don't help with OP's case - `func` defined in `c.h` will still be available in `a.c` even if you add include guards to all of the `.h` files. My recommendation is what's found in real-world cases - not using functions directly in `.h` files, but rather `.c` files.

Comment: Unless you and I mean different things by include guards? I'm referring to e.g. `#ifndef _B_H_` sort of guards for `b.h`

Comment: I think the problem is that the question is poor.  I'm interpreting it according to the headline, but you seem to be interpreting it according to the last sentence of the body.  Any way around, the OP exhibits lack of conceptual foundation.  In its present form, the question would have been better unanswered, but I will lift my DV if you edit this answer (the DV is too old for me to lift it otherwise).

Comment: Okay, on rereading the title I can understand the confusion - I found it a bit nonsensible so I addressed only the question body :). Will edit my answer with a bit more details.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Include guards don't help here, as we don't have the case of one source (directly or indirectly) including the same header twice. The title also refers to "stopping an inclusion" in general.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but please don't use reserved identifiers for the names of the include guard macros.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, this ...

> here i want to restrict a.c from acessing fun

... has nothing in particular to do with header files or `#include`.  If `fun` is defined as an external function anywhere in the program, then it can be called from anywhere else in the program, headers notwithstanding.  This is merely a question of knowing the function's name and at least something about its signature.  With that information, any source file can provide its own compatible declaration of the function to enable the call (and some compilers might even accept the call without a declaration).

If you want to restrict the locations from which `fun()` can be called (directly, by name) then declare it `static`, and move its definition to the (only) C source file from which you want it to be callable.

As far as ...

> How to stop the inclusion of file imported in a file , the file in
> which the latter has been included in C

... goes, you can't do that, strictly speaking.  If `a.c` contains an `#include "b.h"` directive that is processed, and, in the context of processing that directive, `b.h` contains an `#include "c.h"` directive that is processed then the effect is to include the contents of `c.h` in `a.c`. Period.

If `b.h` contains an `#include` directive that you want to avoid being processed under some circumstances then conditional compilation directives (`#if`, `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`) are the way to do so.  "Include guards" are a particularly common example, and as a matter of style and convention, every header should guard its body via appropriate include guards.  If your `c.h` did that then it would resolve the duplicate function definition error you get from `a.c` directly including both `b.h` and `c.h`:

### c.h

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

// everything else ...

#endif
```

Of course, `b.h` should have its own include guards, too.

But even more importantly, **avoid putting function or variable definitions in header files in the first place**.  Put only *declarations* into header files (and provide prototypes):

```
void f(void);
```

The actual definitions belong in regular source files (.c), and regular source files should never be `#include`d by any other file.  This is the way to share declarations of external functions and objects among translation units without inviting duplicate definitions.